# Black and white squares puzzle

Tags: pattern

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this puzzle?

Original source: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSer3_g_HTAdsaFRGZVheFXc7ZhaktYKdW2JB_ah00vy59NUng/viewform

Comment: The google form you got this seems to be some sort of quiz. Are you allowed to post this here?

Comment: @tom I know, I'm just wondering if the quiz is an open quiz, and whether this puzzle should be allowed to be reopened

Comment: @Ash - please do a better job of explaining where you found the problem because it looks like you are just trying to send us to your quiz. It would **really** help if you put more into your question ...;. e.g. I found this problem in an online survey - see <<insert link>>

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil yes. I don't think this Q should be used to drive traffic to the survey, but if it is explained then it would not be so bad.

Comment: My guess is that Ash isn't the maker of the online thing trying to drive traffic to it, but someone who's trying to _do_ the online thing and looking for help. Ash, it would be very helpful to know more. What _is_ the Google Forms document you've pointed us at? How did you find it? Whose is it?

Comment: Why dis you post it [twice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/96935/63533)?

Comment: Because the first time it got closed pending attribution, and Ash made the common error of posting a new version instead of editing the old one. An easy mistake to make.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan I apologise. I am literally new to all this. Was just desperate to get the solution so didn't take care of other aspects about my post. Will make sure to abide by the rules next time. Cheers for all the help.

Comment: We do still need to know what this thing is and whether you have the creator's permission to post it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> **B**. Flip the middle column blocks around the central horizontal axis, and **AND** it with the left block in the row to get the right block.

Comment: Boy, is that concise or what!

Comment: @JMP, did you do this on paper or in your own head? I did not have paper and pen with me at the time of solving this, which made this particular problem harder.

Comment: In my head. You can see that the top two left and right blocks have two blocks in common, b,c,e fit the pattern, and b has a neat match to the bottom middle block.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> C completes the pattern if you count the number of black squares vertically and horizontally, it would be 8, 10, 14, both ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think JMP, in his answer, considers the order of the blocks as well.